# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.whatsappback.Models.Message

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this Error, **App is crashing every time when I try to send messages**

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.whatsappback.Models.Message
>
> at com.example.whatsappback.Activities.ChatActivity$1.onDataChange(ChatActivity.java:63)

Which is:

```
Message message = snapshot1.getValue(Message.class);
```

**This is My ChatActivity**
Here I am getting the Error

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActivityChatBinding binding;
MessagesAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Message>messages;
FirebaseDatabase database;

String senderRoom, receiverRoom;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    messages = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MessagesAdapter(this, messages);

    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String receiverUid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
    String senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();


    senderRoom = senderUid+receiverUid;
    receiverRoom = receiverUid+senderUid;

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    database.getReference().child("chats")
            .child(senderRoom)
            .child("messages")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                messages.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Message message = snapshot1.getValue(Message.class);
                    messages.add(message);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });


    binding.sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String messageTxt = binding.messageBox.getText().toString();
            Date date = new Date();
            Message message = new Message(messageTxt, senderUid, date.getTime());
            binding.messageBox.setText("");


            database.getReference().child("chats")
                    .child(senderRoom)
                    .child("messages")
                    .push()
                    .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    database.getReference().child("chats")
                            .child(receiverRoom)
                            .child("messages")
                            .push()
                            .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}}
```

**This is The Model Class Message.java**

```
public class Message {

private String messageId, message, senderId;
private long timeStamp;
private int feeling;

public Message() {
}

public Message(String message, String senderId, long timeStamp) {
    this.message = message;
    this.senderId = senderId;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

public String getMessageId() {
    return messageId;
}

public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
    this.messageId = messageId;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getSenderId() {
    return senderId;
}

public void setSenderId(String senderId) {
    this.senderId = senderId;
}

public long getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

public int getFeeling() {
    return feeling;
}

public void setFeeling(int feeling) {
    this.feeling = feeling;
}
```

}

**My JSON FILE** where I the first one is Chats Database and Second One is Users who login in the App

```
{"chats" : {
"3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L23GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2" : {
  "messages" : {
    "-MsW3CCOLw1CRDYWahl4" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "hi",
      "senderId" : "3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2",
      "timeStamp" : 1641232243332
    },
    "-MsYWOVMOe17EMptWwlS" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "hhhhh",
      "senderId" : "3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2"
    }}},
"3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L27JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1" : {
  "messages" : {
    "-MsW6Lem6hq_hxZjeOQA" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "helloo",
      "senderId" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1",
      "timeStamp" : 1641233081867
    },
    "feeling" : 0,
    "message" : "hi",
    "senderId" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1",
    "timeStamp" : 1641231670227
  }
},
"3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2AYha5pt6tGgzPa0e4WJLr8wSakk2" : {
  "messages" : {
    "-MsYtwRyavktJc8hwonR" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "",
      "senderId" : "3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2"
    },
    "-MsYtwwvlBe0Ocdvlggu" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "",
      "senderId" : "3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2"
    },
  }
},
"7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg13GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2" : {
  "messages" : {
    "-MsW6L_AmpIryN0DBjyt" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "helloo",
      "senderId" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1",
      "timeStamp" : 1641233081867
    },
    "-MsW8eU0KN4Ge8bC1ktq" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "hi",
      "senderId" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1",
      "timeStamp" : 1641233687661
    },
    "feeling" : 0,
    "message" : "hi",
    "senderId" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1",
    "timeStamp" : 1641231670227
  }
},
"AYha5pt6tGgzPa0e4WJLr8wSakk23GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2" : {
  "messages" : {
    "-MsYtw_o0dnh8meRwdI9" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "",
      "senderId" : "3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2"
    },
  }
}
```

This one is Users DataBase

```
"users" : {
"3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2" : {
  "name" : "Om Swami",
  "phoneNumber" : "+919887012345",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-back.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2F3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2?alt=media&token=be73d814-99cf-4fb4-8d9c-78aa1144a8e7",
  "uid" : "3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L2"
},
"7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1" : {
  "name" : "Prinshu❣️",
  "phoneNumber" : "+9197864110",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-back.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2F7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1?alt=media&token=2fb22085-3644-4703-b782-f3500dcce2b1",
  "uid" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1"
},
"AYha5pt6tGgzPa0e4WJLr8wSakk2" : {
  "name" : "Ishmita Om",
  "phoneNumber" : "+91988782409",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-back.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FAYha5pt6tGgzPa0e4WJLr8wSakk2?alt=media&token=63ff351c-f2d0-485f-9dfa-e396e94ebbc7",
  "uid" : "AYha5pt6tGgzPa0e4WJLr8wSakk2"
}
```

}
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Sir I m doing that but it is saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."  while I have remove unnecessary code

Comment: Then try to add some explications to that code.

Comment: Pleasee Check Sir

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Message` class.

Comment: Done Sir Please Check

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the second room in the JSON you shared:

```
"3GJBWzyjbVfAJQkhMIFzrr2KG2L27JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1" : {
  "messages" : {
    "-MsW6Lem6hq_hxZjeOQA" : {
      "feeling" : 0,
      "message" : "helloo",
      "senderId" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1",
      "timeStamp" : 1641233081867
    },
    "feeling" : 0,
    "message" : "hi",
    "senderId" : "7JyFKNV0k6e4cwM8zNOb1coANfg1",
    "timeStamp" : 1641231670227
  }
},
```

Here you first have a message with key `-MsW6Lem6hq_hxZjeOQA` that looks fine, but then you have the properties of another message right under the `messages` node, so without a parent key.

So in your `onDataChange` when you loop over the results with `DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()`, you first get the `-MsW6Lem6hq_hxZjeOQA` node and that goes fine. But next `snapshot1` becomes `"feeling" : 0` and when you then call `snapshot1.getValue(Message.class)` that throws the error.

The solution is ensure your message properties are always stored under a push key. I recommend enforcing that in [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules).

Comment: thank you sir it is working now, I deleted all the chats from the firebase and run again the app nd it is working

Comment: Yes Why Not?? Sir